# jQuery append does not apply CSS styling

Tags: jquery, css

My jquery code is appending a piece of HTML in code properly, but the CSS styles are not applied after the HTML has been appended.

What is the right way to do it?

This is how I am doing:

```
if(listone[i] != "")
{
    var l1pos = listone[i];
    $('ul.ulstep1 li').eq(i).addClass('selected');

    $line1= '<div class="tagless ';
    $line2 = i;
    $line2='><div class="tagleft"></div><span>';
    $line2 += listone[i];
    $line3  = '</span><div class="tagright"></div></div>';
    $('.quiztags').append($line1+$line2+$line3);
    $('.quiztags').append($('<div></div>').attr('class', 'tagless'));
}
```

This gives me the right HTML but no styling is applied.
I am doing this operation inside a javascript onload function, so the CSS should have loaded when this is executed, right?

Comment: Just eyeballing it and it doesn't look like you're closing your class attribute after `$line2 = i;`

Comment: could you post the html that is generated? (via firebug or equivalent), and if the html is valid?

Comment: The statement `'$line2 = i;` does nothing as line2 it is overwritten in next line

Comment: By the way, you could avoid syntax issues like this by using `.addClass` instead. Something like this: `$('<div/>').addClass('tagless').addClass(i).appendTo($('.quiztags'));`

Comment: @Muleskinner good point, still line2 is not closing the class attribute.

Comment: @OriginalSyn touché! totally agree, the code submitted by OP is somehow sloppy here and there

Answer (score 1):

Try it, maybe it works.

```
if(listone[i] != "")
{
    $('ul.ulstep1 li').eq(i).addClass('selected');
    var line1   = '<div class="tagless ';
    var line2   = i;
    line2       += '"><div class="tagleft"></div><span>';
    line2       += listone[i];
    var line3   = '</span><div class="tagright"></div></div>';
    $('.quiztags').append(line1+line2+line3);
    $('.quiztags').append($('<div></div>').attr('class', 'tagless'));
}
```